# Viewport in JavaFX webView

Tags: webview, javafx, viewport

Can anyone say how to set view port in JavaFX web view.
 i need this solution for my project. So please suggest any solution to do so.
Actually am rendering html page in webview. while rendering is there any image inside that html page. Scroll option is coming

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic code you need

```
WebView browser = new WebView();
WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();
webEngine.load("http://example.com");
```

For a full guide on how to implement:
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm

Here's the example source:
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/WebViewSample.zip

Comment: Hi buddy i hope u dont know about our JavafX WebEngine it wont support Viewport only Android webview only supports this. As ViewPort is a view which will shrint our entire webpage into our browser Width. please check if u any doubt in my answer.. please pass any page with with of nearly 2000 nad height of =1500. i hope u understand my question.

Comment: I don't fully understand, but it sounds like you have a problem setting the HTML width. Withouth any screenshots or code, I guess you need to set your HTML viewport meta tag to `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=100px;height=100px;"> Actually viewport word will make our html content to fit our browser size.. but this viewport functioanlity will works fine in all the external browsers and also in Android webview but will not work in our javafx webview